# Generate models from existing tables using Rails 3

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, model

Using `Rails 3.2.2` and `ruby 1.9.3dev` and mysql

I am new to ruby and rails. We have an existing database with a couple hundred tables. We would like to try out rails to see if it would be a positive change from PHP & ZendFramework.

Migrating data into another database is not an option for us because we have several other applications currently using this database. We wanted to "attach" a rails project to the existing database.

The part I am struggling is generating all the models from our existing database.

I seen a couple of older posts talking about some automated techniques including [Magic Model Generator](http://magicmodels.rubyforge.org/magic_model_generator/). While others talked about there is no way to do this, or you just have create them all manually.

I was not successful in generating models using Magic Model Generator (perhaps rails 2 only?)

Long ago, when we switched to ZendFramework, I wrote a quick script to analyze the database and generate all the model files for us. It would seem this would be a somewhat common scenario.

Note: We use `ID` instead of `id` and many have many `foreign_key` relationships.

So I wanted to ask the community what is the best (way/practice) to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that difficult, just takes a bit more configuration. Here's a basic template for a model:

```
class YourIdealModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = `actual_table_name`
  self.primary_key = `ID`

  belongs_to :other_ideal_model, 
    :foreign_key => 'foreign_key_on_other_table'

  has_many :some_other_ideal_models, 
    :foreign_key => 'foreign_key_on_this_table', 
    :primary_key => 'primary_key_on_other_table'
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the template, this was actually the route I was considering. However, I thought there would be a tool which could do this already.

Comment: Instead of magic models generator, you can try magic models. It won't generate the model files but you will have them available in your app, and I've successfully used it in a rails 3 app.

Comment: You can start with this: https://github.com/drnic/dr-nic-magic-models You will need to do some hackery to get this working on Rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert and even had researched about this.
Without thinking to much first solution in my mind is to make the models and migrations according to the rails way so you don't have any problem, for example key and foreign key naming. If you have already some data you should migrate it to the rails db.

One reason to do this is that models are suppose not to be only data accessors but also contain the business logic

Comment: Thanks for your idea. Migrating data into another database is not an option for us because we have several other applications currently using this database. We wanted to "attach" a rails project to the database.