# Auto generation of classes based on existing database in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rubygems

Currently, I am manually creating individual classes in rails to mapped it to an existing database. I am curious if there are any gems out there that could help me scaffold rails model for all the existing tables.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931475/generate-models-from-existing-tables-using-rails-3

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try with [RMRE](https://github.com/bosko/rmre). It generates your models and all the `has_many` and `belongs_to` relationships based on your db foreign keys.